# Cannot get visitor's public IP in Google Cloud Compute engine instance (container cluster created)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, clientip

Recently I deployed a website in google cloud container cluster, and I believe that the actual website source code is run inside the computer engine instance which created by cluster automatically.

In the website, I want to log the visitor's access info including the public IP address, e.g. 80.87.131.131. But I found that I only can get the internal IP address, like 10.128.0.3

Here is the PHP function I used to get the visitor's IP.

```
function get_ip()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}
```

Is there any way to get the visitor's public IP? Do I need to make some server side configurations? Any help will be appreciated. And thanks very much in advance.

Comment: So, does it work for you?

Comment: usually the function above is working, but in Google Cloud (kubernetes) Cluster pods, the function only return the internal IP, like 10.100.xxx.xxx. I think Google Cloud may have some special configurations for the cluster pod. I didn't have time to do more research about it and I have switch to JS to get the function done. See my comment to the first answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

This script records visitor's IP in a text file.

```
<?php
function scoate_ip(){
if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')){
$ip=getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
} else {
$ip=getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
}
return $ip;
}
$ip_trimis = scoate_ip();

$locatie = fopen("IP/IP.txt","a+");
fwrite ($locatie, "\n".$ip_trimis."\n");
fclose($locatie);
?>
```

You may want to edit it as you wish. `$ip_trimis` is the visitor's IP.

Comment: Thank you for your help. And I gave up using PHP and used JS to get visitor's IP details. There is a free JS library I can use and I believe that it is free, freegeoip.net.

Comment: I am glad it works that way however JS is client based and if your visitor has JS deactivated, this won't work.